# Centrar color en gradiente de Canvas html5

Tags: html, html5, css3, canvas

tengo el siguiente gradiente en canvas.

https://jsfiddle.net/palaceslittle/tdL5nqe2/2/

**Mi pregunta es: 
¿Porqué si tengo seteado el rojo en 0.5, no aparece en la mitad de la barra?**

**¿Cómo logro que mi color aparezca justo en el centro ?**
**¿Cómo funciona el sistema de gradiente?**

<sub>MIRAR EN PANTALLA COMPLETA</sub>

```js
function fade() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var gradient = canvas.getContext("2d").createLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 500);

    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'gray');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'red');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'red');
    gradient.addColorStop(1.0, 'gray');

    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 800);
}

fade();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="800"></canvas>
```

Comment: Pon el codigo aqui en el snippet de codigo.. asi la gente no tiene que irse a jsfiddle

Comment: @lois6b , ahí lo inserte. Gracias por la recomendación.

Comment: @nawelittle, te resultó útil mi respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

El problema son las coordenadas que has indicado al crear el `gradient`.

Los parámetros que recibe [createLinearGradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createLinearGradient) son:

> `CanvasGradient ctx.createLinearGradient(x0, y0, x1, y1);`
>
> Donde:
> `x0`: El eje `x` de la coordenada del punto de inicio.
> `y0`: El eje `y` de la coordenada del punto de inicio.
> `x1`: El eje `x` de la coordenada del punto de final.
> `y1`: El eje `y` de la coordenada del punto de final.

Es decir, que si el `canvas` mide `800px` y quieres que el rojo este exactamente al medio puedes hacer 2 cosas:

- **OP1:** Indicar que el `gradient` vaya hasta los `800px` (`eg: y1 = 800`)
- **OP2**: Indicar que el `gradient` empieza a los `300px` (`eg: y0 = 300`), que es exactamente la misma distancia que hay desde el fin del `gradient` al borde inferior del `canvas`

Ejemplo usando `OP1`

```js
function fade() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var gradient = canvas.getContext("2d").createLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 800);

    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'gray');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'red');
        gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'red');
    gradient.addColorStop(1.0, 'gray');

    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 800);
}

fade();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="800"></canvas>
```